# Spread data to create unique rows

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame that I want to reshape so that for each medid, there is only one row. I know that I can use spread to accomplish this, but it's not looking at all how I want to look and I just can't wrap my head around the concept when I read blogs, tutorials, etc. and I'm just not sure where I'm going amiss.

My data currently looks like

```
   medid year dose drug
1    101 2001  500    A
2    101 2002  600    A
3    101 2003  750    A
4    101 2004  550    A
5    102 2001  300    B
6    102 2002  330    B
7    102 2003  350    B
8    102 2004  390    B
9    103 2001  100    C
10   103 2002   NA    C
11   103 2003  250    C
12   103 2004  125    C
```

but I want it to look like

```
  medid  dose.2001 dose.2002 dose.2003 dose.2004 drug.2001 drug.2002 drug.2003 drug.2004
1   101       500       600       750       550         A         A         A         A
2   102       300       330       350       390         B         B         B         B
3   103       100        NA       250       125         C         C         C         C
```

I've tried to use `spread()` but it doesn't give me unique row for each GEOID, and it just isn't looking how I want.

```
df <- data.frame(medid=c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103),
                 year=c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004),
                 dose=c(500, 600, 750, 550, 300, 330, 350, 390, 100, NA, 250, 125),
                 drug=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"))
df %>% spread(year, medid)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `tidyr::pivot_wider`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyr::pivot_wider`, as @Cettt suggested:

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df, names_from=year, values_from=c(drug, dose), names_sep=".")
# # A tibble: 3 x 9
#   medid drug.2001 drug.2002 drug.2003 drug.2004 dose.2001 dose.2002 dose.2003 dose.2004
#   <dbl> <fct>     <fct>     <fct>     <fct>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1   101 A         A         A         A               500       600       750       550
# 2   102 B         B         B         B               300       330       350       390
# 3   103 C         C         C         C               100        NA       250       125
```